# how to do preg_match and replace string data using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi I need to fetch price from this below tags, I have no idea about preg functions in php first time I am using. Please solve this

TAG_1:

```
<span id="hs18Price" itemprop="price" title="Price of Intex Aqua N2 Dual SIM Android Mobile Phone - White">
<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>&nbsp;5999</span>
```

TAG_2:

```
<div class="video-price-txt"><big>Intex Aqua N2 Dual SIM Android Mobile Phone - White Price: Rs. 5999 </big></div>
```

for tag_2 i have tried one method but it is giving entire string value, I need only Price value "5999", instead of this i am getting like below for tag_2.

Method: `if(preg_match('/<div class="video-price-txt"><big>(.*?)<\/big><\/div>/',get_page($url),$matches2))`

TAG_2 OUT PUT: `'price' => string 'Intex Aqua N2 Dual SIM Android Mobile Phone - White Price: Rs. 5999 ' (length=68)`

Please suggest me how to get only price numeric values from these two TAGS

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I am struggling from two days I have no idea how to mark tag for price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the number, try this simple regex:

```
preg_match( '/Rs.\s?(\d+)/', get_page( $url ), $matches );
```

You should than have the value in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Thank You but value not matching it is giving 2500 instead of 5999. I think Rs. string matching with another tag.

Comment: Probably because you `get_page()` function returns the whole website? Than sourround my regex with your some HTML markup: `/<big>.*Rs.\s?(\d+)\s?<\/big>/`